# Lombok with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, code-generation, lombok

Is this possible? Haven't seen much discussion on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have never tried Lombok with Hibernate but I don't see why it shouldn't work.
Also, take a look here: http://groups.google.com/group/project-lombok/browse_thread/thread/294bd52d9d8695df/7bc6b0f343831af1?lnk=gst&q=hibernate#7bc6b0f343831af1

Also, [Lombok project release notes](http://projectlombok.org/changelog.html) mention Hibernate explicitely.

Answer (score 29):

Sure! It works great from my experience. Here's an example entity:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class PingerEntity {
    // ID
    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    // USER
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private UserEntity user;


    // URL
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String url;


    /**
     * The number of seconds between checks
     */
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int frequency; 


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public MonitorType monitorType;
}
```

Comment: If you use Data, you don't have to put Getter and Setter on each field. You might want to also specify EqualsAndHashcode(of={"id"})

Comment: @RoelSpilker Yes but be careful with entities having OneToMany and ManyToOne, because the ToString of lombok will make an infinite loop.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for, I had an infinite loop for one of these entities and it caused a stackoverflowerror. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @qwertzguy : Could you please elaborate further on your reply stated above. I am missing your point.

Comment: @ecdhe basically having an entity that links to the other and itself links back to the first one. They will then each call toString on each other repeatedly.

Comment: @qwertzguy now I understand it much better. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use it also with @Data (and it works !)

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

Comment: I had problems with @Data annotation and hibernate.
First problme was with hashCode() generated method, hibernate just failed to create entitry. Other one with toString() method in case model cantains Lists or Sets.
Just #Setter #Getter so far so good. #ToString only if model conatins only plain data fields

Comment: in fact it doesn't! This article explains why in details https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example; `Library.java`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor // JPA
@Entity
@Table(name = "libraries")
public class Library {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  // This will be included in the json
  private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonIgnore
  public void addBook(Book book) {
    books.add(book);
    book.setLibrary(this);
  }
}
```

And `Book.java`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor // JPA
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  private String title;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "library_id") // Owning side of the relationship
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @JsonIgnore // Avoid infinite loops
  private Library library;
}
```